# how to achieve this complex UI?

Tags: flutter

Any ideas to paint this UI using flutter.

i tried using custom clipper with stack position widget but the check icon not placed into the center of triangle. so if someone tried same UI could help me to make this UI. also how to place icon in the center of traingle

[image]

Comment: Container with border, Text and a ClipPath widget, check out this video for ClipPath https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vT4TzQhyJkM

Comment: My OCD is kicking in.  Shouldn't that be "Pediatrics"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ClipPath` and define a `CustomClipper<Path>` for it:
Using a `Stack` put a blue rectangle first and then a white one with a blue border and clip its bottom right corner using the `ClipPath`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ClippedButton(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ClippedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const ClippedButton({
    Key? key,
    this.clipSize = 60,
    this.size = const Size(300, 100),
    this.iconSize = 24,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double clipSize;
  final Size size;
  final double iconSize;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double horizontalAlignment =
        (size.width - clipSize / 2 + iconSize / 2) / size.width;
    final double verticalAlignment =
        (size.height - clipSize / 2 + iconSize / 2) / size.height;

    return SizedBox(
      width: size.width,
      height: size.height,
      child: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          Container(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
          ClipPath(
            clipper: MyClipper(clipSize),
            child: Container(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                border: Border.all(width: 4, color: Colors.blueAccent),
              ),
              child: const Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Peditatrics',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent, fontSize: 40),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment(horizontalAlignment, verticalAlignment),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.check,
              size: iconSize,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  final double clipSize;

  MyClipper(this.clipSize);

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper oldClipper) => true;

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final Path path = Path();
    path
      ..moveTo(0, 0)
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height - clipSize)
      ..lineTo(size.width - clipSize, size.height)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height)
      ..lineTo(0, 0);
    return path;
  }
}
```

For the check mark icon placement can have a simple logic like the one in the code to place it in the center of the triangle.

[image]